# Clean Tomcat's working directory with IntelliJ

Tags: tomcat, intellij-idea, application-server

I'm using IntelliJ 14 for deploying a Spring App to my local Tomcat 8 installation (Windows).

I recently changed the letter casing of some file names and it seems that Tomcat's working directory is not updated correctly (propably the fault of Windows's case-insensitive filesystem).

**How do I clean Tomcat 8's working directory with IntelliJ?**

Answer (score 10, accepted):

IntelliJ creates the Tomcat cache at `C:\Users\<your-username>\.IntelliJIdea<year>.<version>\system\tomcat`. You can delete this folder to get the cache clean.

For Windows, the folder is `c:\Users\<your-username>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea<year>.<version>\tomcat\`

**Attention!** Be sure to clean the browser cache. If you use Chrome, F12>Application Tab>Clear storage>Click Clear site data

[image]
Ref:

[Directories used by the IDE to store settings, caches, plugins and logs](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519)

Comment: c:\Users\<your-username>\AppData\Local\JetBrains\IntelliJIdea2022.2\tomcat\